# SafeArray of SafeArrays? Help to transfer VBA code to C++

Tags: c++, excel, com, safearray, vba

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2))
```

such code from above I have at VBA macros. Now the same thing I should create in a C++ code.
As far as I could understand till now - I should use SAFEARRAY type.
But I still do not understand how correctly I should do that.
Main problem - I have practically pure C++ code. No MSVC extensions like COleSafeArray, no ATL support.
The only thing which I can use - STLSoft which is a 100% header-only library
which significantly simplifies the creation of such elements like SAFEARRAY.

But in any way - which structure it should be? 1D SafeArray of 1D SafeArrays of two VT_I4 type elements?

P.S. I should use MinGW + gcc 4.x environment.

Comment: As far as I know, SAFEARRAY is MSVC thing. do not you have any problem with that?

Comment: Oups - sorry - I completely forgot to add that I should work at MinGW+gcc environment.
And SAFEARRAY declaration is simply avaialble for me out-of-box from MinGW.
So - I even did not try to analyse - who was the first Company - who has developed it.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi, no, SAFEARRAY is exactly what gets passed around in VBA/VB6 when you use an array type in a COM exposed method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create a 5x2 safearray of integer arrays with VT_I4 fields...
comstl::variant fieldInfo;
fieldInfo.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
{
    SAFEARRAYBOUND sab[2];
    sab[0].lLbound = 1; sab[0].cElements = 5; // i
    sab[1].lLbound = 1; sab[1].cElements = 2;  // j
    fieldInfo.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 2, sab);
}

// Fill safearray with values like:
/*
   FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2))
 */
// first of all fill the first column with data...
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    VARIANT tmp;
    tmp.vt = VT_I4;
    tmp.lVal = i;
    // Add to safearray...
    long indices[] = {i,1};
    SafeArrayPutElement(fieldInfo.parray, indices, (void *)&tmp);
}
// ...after that - fill the second column.
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    VARIANT tmp;
    tmp.vt = VT_I4;
    tmp.lVal = 2;
    // Add to safearray...
    long indices[] = {i,2};
    SafeArrayPutElement(fieldInfo.parray, indices, (void *)&tmp);
}
```

And this code allowed to me achieve my Goal!